# Шрифт Montserrat не правильно отображается на Макбуке

Tags: html, css, шрифты, web-fonts

У меня всё хорошо отображаеться

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У заказчика на макбуке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где взяли? Как подключаете?

Comment: Скачал в google fonts и сконвертировал под другие форматы.

Comment: Подключат через font-face

Comment: Сейчас попробую скачать с webfonts, и скажу заказчику чтобы протестировал

Comment: «Подключат через font-face» — как будто есть другие способы. Я спрашивал какой конкретно код. И лучше бы его написать прямо в вопросе. Ну и, возможно, у вас просто какая-то ошибка в конвертации.